# Discarding first row and column in 2D matrix - Repeat same for flattened 1D vector

Tags: c++, math, matrix

for a 2D matrxi 3x5 or 5x3 I need to perform mapping of 2D matrix to 1D vector. 
Mapping is ok but skipping the first row and column is where I am lost.

I have a 2D matrix that i am accessing using the following code

```
for (uint i=0;i < 3; i++)
for (uint j=0;j < 5; j++)
{
     if (i == 0 || j == 0)
         continue;
     else
         // result - Do some calculations and store  
         storage(i,j) = result;
}
```

Now I have to convert the 2D matrix to 1D vector and perform the same task.I just cant wrap my head around the condition of i == 0 || j== 0 which is simply leaving out the first row and first column of the 2D matrix. That is, no calculations are performed. 
So if they are left out, means the storage matrix should contain zeros just like it would have been in the two for loops.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So how are you flattening the matrix into a vector? E.g. if it's row-major, matrix entry `(r,c)` will be in the vector location `(r*num_columns+c)`. Therefore, entry `i` in the vector corresponds to row `i/num_columns` and column `i%num_columns`. Skipping certain entries should be straightforward from that.

Comment: What's the problem? Does `storage` not have zeroes where it should? Did you initialize `storage` that way?

Comment: @Beta I have zeros. The problem is that I need to skip the the first row/col when i am in the 1D vector domain.

Comment: @mindriot I will check your solution. I am currently using row-major scheme to flatten the matrix into a vector.

Comment: @mindriot - Thanks for the solution, please post it as an answer so that I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your matrix has `R` rows and `C` columns.  Depending on how your flattened vector represents your matrix, you can calculate the relation between a matrix entry `(r,c)` and the corresponding vector location `i` as follows:

```
Representation |  (r,c) is in    | Entry i corresponds to...
               | vector entry... |    row     |   column
---------------+-----------------+------------+-------------
Row-major      |     (r*C+c)     |   (i/C)    |    (i%C)
Column-major   |     (c*R+r)     |   (i%R)    |    (i/R)
```

So if you iterate over your vector entries and calculate the corresponding matrix row and column using the appropriate formulas, you can check and skip entries based on the calculated row and column number.